# run a cmd command from powershell script

Tags: command-line-interface, graphviz, powershell-5.1

I am trying to run a program called Graphviz in the later stage of a PowerShell script I have to collect and create employee information to make an orgchart

[script located here](https://github.com/rbarbrow/AzureADGraphvizOrgChart/blob/master/AzureADGraphvizOrgChart.ps1)

in windows command prompt (cmd) it would be executed as like this

Create an SVG from DOT file:

```
dot -Tsvg -o path/to/out_file.svg path/to/file.dot
```

I may be overthinking this but I don't know how to execute a program in PowerShell with arguments

Thank you in advance

(comments on my script are welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding double quotes to your script worked for me:

```
cmd.exe \c "C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin\dot.exe" -Tdot abc.gv
```

Comment: can you use variables?   like cmd.exe /c  $dotpath -Tdot $outputpath

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```powershell-5
    Invoke-Expression -Command "dot -rest of command here"
```

works.

And also, addressing Crash893's question in comments, variables can be used this way too

```powershell
    Invoke-Expression -Command "dot -anoption $inputfile $outfile"
```